# Flexbox, wrap items by column

Tags: css

I am trying to control the position of some blocks contained in a wrapper with flexbox functionalities. Here is what I want at the end:

[image]

Here is the markup I would like to use. I wish not to change it and visually organize my box with CSS:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list-1">
    Liste 1
  </div>
  <div class="list-2">
    Liste 2
  </div>
  <div class="list-3">
    Liste 3
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried multiple things but it does not work. Here is the closest thing I came with, but list-3 only starts when list-2 also starts:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
div[class^="list-"] {
  text-align: center;
}
.list-1 {
  background: red;
  flex-basis: 80%;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.list-2 {
  background: pink;
  flex-basis: 80%;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.list-3 {
  background: green;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list-1">
    Liste 1
  </div>
  <div class="list-2">
    Liste 2
  </div>
  <div class="list-3">
    Liste 3
  </div>
</div>
```

**Is it even possible? Thank you for your help.**

Comment: extra-hackish with flex, why not css-grid ??

Comment: Ho, well I didn't know it existed, shame on me, I'm going to check it out! I'm completely open to not use flexbox

Comment: Than this should be exactly what you are after.

Comment: I agree with @philipp on this, CSS grid would indead be the way to go for this layout if you do not wish to change your markup.

Comment: Well, it seems to work! https://jsfiddle.net/2z5haer7/2/ Thank you very much guys. I don't know if you can still respond to the question since it has been marked as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

try this code

add `div` to `first  and second list` and use `flex-basis:80% for new div`

i add class

```
.list {
  flex-basis: 80%;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

div[class^="list-"] {
  text-align: center;
}

.list-1 {
  background: red;
  flex-basis: 80%;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.list-2 {
  background: pink;
  flex-basis: 80%;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.list-3 {
  background: green;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.list {
  flex-basis: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list-1">
      Liste 1
    </div>
    <div class="list-2">
      Liste 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-3">
    Liste 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, that would work but as stated in my question it would change my html markup and "I wish not to change it and visually organize my box with CSS". But thank you for taking the time to help me! I'm going to try what @philipp commented about `css-grid`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch; /* this is for the children of flex to be of equal height. */
}
div[class^="list-"] {
  text-align: center;
}
.list-1 {
  background: red;
  line-height: 200px;
  height:200px;
}
.list-2 {
  background: pink;
  line-height: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
.list-3 {
  background: green;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  /* following 3 codes is for centered the liste3. deletable */
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.column {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex:4;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="column">
  <div class="list-1">
    Liste 1
  </div>
  <div class="list-2">
    Liste 2
  </div>
   </div>
  <div class="list-3">
    Liste 3
  </div>
</div>
```